# Passing parameters by reference

Tags: ruby

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @foo = 1
    @bar = 1
  end
  def change(a, b) 
    a += 1
    b -= 1   
  end 
  def print
    change(@foo,@bar)
    puts "#{@foo},#{@bar}"
  end
end
```

Since variable `foo` and  `bar` may be modified together many times in this class, I was wondering whether I can use one method to do this job. I want to print `2,0` in method `print` while I still get `1,1` in above code. Is there a simple way to write such a method in Ruby?

Comment: why do you think the original value will not change? Can you give a bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Usually you do not want to pass by reference like this.

Comment: That still tells nothing about what are you trying to do. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What I'm trying do is to write a method which can modify its parameters' value and let the caller be able to see the modifications. Suppose there is another variable `@abc`. after calling `change(@foo, @abc)`, I want the caller to see the value of `@foo` is added by 1. Same for `@abc`

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @foo = 1
    @bar = 1
  end
  def change(a, b) 
    a += 1
    b -= 1
    [a, b]   
  end 
  def print
    @foo, @bar = change(@foo,@bar)
    puts "#{@foo},#{@bar}"
  end
end
```

You could do something like this in Ruby but it is more advanced since passing by reference is not built in.

It will result in even harder to understand source code. With unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are immutable objects in Ruby so you can't modify them that way. `a += 1` just reassigns local variable `a` with new value, it doesn't modify the original object (1).

In order to achieve what you want (although you haven't really explained what you want), you have several possibilities:

- Wrap integers in objects (which is cumbersome for such a trivial example)
- Use mutable objects rather than integers, such as hashes.

For example:

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @foo_bar = { foo: 1, bar: 1 }
  end
  def change(a, b) 
    @foo_bar[a] += 1
    @foo_bar[b] -= 1
  end 
  def print
    change(:foo,:bar)
    puts "#{@foo_bar[:foo]},#{@foo_bar[:bar]}"
  end
end
```

Also, a remark: it is really rare that one has need to pass an object's instance variable as a parameter to the method of the same object (`change(@foo,@bar)` in your example). Instance variables are meant for keeping object's internal state.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby actually can do this, but it's not as clear as you think. In Ruby, all variables are just references to objects. So:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > def m(a)
2.0.0p0 :002?>   a << 1
2.0.0p0 :003?>   a
2.0.0p0 :004?> end
 => nil
2.0.0p0 :005 > a = [3,2]
 => [3, 2]
2.0.0p0 :006 > m(a)
 => [3, 2, 1]
2.0.0p0 :007 > a
 => [3, 2, 1]
```

However, integers are immutable. So, you *can't* do the same with an integer variable. You see, +=, -=, *=, etc. are all really just `var = var +/-/* rhs`. This only modifies the reference stored in the local variable, and not in the variable that was passed. You really have two options:

1. Use a mutable object: Use something like a Hash, Array, etc. -- and make sure to use destructive operations like `<<`, `flatten!`, etc.
2. Wrap an Integer in a simple, mutable object: Write a mutable wrapper class that will let you do this.